# Chrome is opening links in to new tabs on a terminal server

Tags: terminal-server, google-chrome

I have Google Chrome installed on a terminal servers. The problem that I am having, some time when a user click on a link it open it into a new tab and not the same tab. event the html code for that link is not set to open into a new page.

To temporary solve the problem we completely close out chrome and re-open it. It seems like some hot key changes the behavior of the browser.

What is causing this to happen? and how can I prevent it from happening in Google Chrome?

Thanks

Comment: Is the user's Ctrl key stuck?

Comment: no. In fact this is happening to many people and not to only one person.

Comment: Did you check if there are some Google Chrome "Extensions" installed/enabled that could cause this ? Also, some have reported that clearing all history solved this issue...

Comment: I don't have any extensions installed. When closing Chrome and re-opening it then the problem is resolved until it happens again.